# Huge different of Average response time between GUI mode and non-GUI mode on Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am getting huge different of Average response time between GUI mode and non-GUI mode on Jmeter.

With  GUI-Mode : 2777 Ms and Non-GUI : 5412 Ms.
With 1 thread, 1 RampupTime , 1 Loopcount , 100 Sample request.

How ever both the test are ran on same machine.
Which results should be considered.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick to non-GUI results because:

1. When you launch JMeter [it tells](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/a75fc427de8ce6ce80d3f39e955dda9c68d01483/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/JMeter.java#L369) you to use GUI only for tests development and/or debugging:

   [image]
2. From [Load Test running](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#load_test_running) chapter of JMeter Documentation

   > Once everything is ready, you will use CLI mode (Command-line mode previously called Non-GUI mode) to run it for the Load Test.
   >
   > `Don't run load test using GUI mode !`
3. From Writing a Visualizer chapter of JMeter Documentation:

   > Load Testing in GUI mode being a bad practice, you should not develop such plugin.
4. From [Reduce Resource Requirements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean) chapter of JMeter Documentation

   > Use CLI mode: `jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l test.jtl`

My expectation is that in non-GUI mode you're creating more intensive load because JMeter doesn't waste time and resources onto updating the GUI and rendering the results (especially if you have [Listeners](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing) added to your test plan)

Comment: I have kept 100 concurrent users only. This itself is making huge difference in response time between CLI any hi mode.